# How to delete a column from a view

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to delete a column from a view but can't seem to be able to do it because apparently is missing a keyword. Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

```
ALTER VIEW REORDERINFO DROP COLUMN name;
```

After trying again I got the following:

```
SQL> ALTER VIEW REORDERINFO
AS SELECT isbn,title, phone
FROM books JOIN publisher USING (pubid);
```

> ERROR at line 2: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot use `ALTER VIEW` for removing a column. To recreate the view without the column, use `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW`.

From the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_4004.htm#SQLRF01104):

> Use the `ALTER VIEW` statement to explicitly recompile a view that is invalid or to
>   modify view constraints.
>
> [image]

Source: Oracle® Database
SQL Language Reference
11g Release 2 (11.2)
E26088-01