How to block migrations that delete a view in django?
When we change the type of a column in Django and run a migration, it does not finish if any view is using the column. However, when we remove a column from the table and run a migration, Django does not interrupt the migration. How can I configure this?
Can we create a custom migration or even a trigger in the database?

Delete a view? or a table?

When I remove a field from a table in the model and run the migration, the database deletes the view that used that field. However, Django doesn't warn me, it just runs everything without warning me.

@GrabielWade: you typically can not delete a column from a view, only from a table: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12660660/67579

I know, but I'm saying that I'm removing a field from my model and when I run migration the database is correctly without the field, but Django doesn't warn that a view based on the table was deleted because I removed a field.

typically Django does not know anything about views (it doesn't create these, manages these, inspects these). So if you built views on top of a table managed by Django, that indeed can have impact.
